# expecting a ';' or an invalid '/'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

This is probably something really simple that I am blind to see, but the errors being given are to vague to tell me where to look.

This line is telling me it is expecting ';'

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
```

I am using VS2010, MVC 2, and I am calling a parial view(ascx file) with this line

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("problemPage");%>
```

However for this line that calls the page I get, error CS1525: Invalid expression term '/'

Here is what is in the partial view(problemPage) that is supposedly where the problem is.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

<style type="text/css">
   a.navfooter:link {color: #19abdc; text-decoration: underline; }
   a.navfooter:visited {color: #19abdc; text-decoration: underline; }
   a.navfooter:hover {color: #19abdc; text-decoration: underline; }
   a.navquicklinks:active {color: #19abdc; } 
</style>

<table width="170" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><h1><a href="../about-this.php"><img src="<%: Url.Content(~/Content/Images/banner_left.gif) %>" width="120" height="600" border="0" /></a></h1>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </td>
<td align="center"><img src="<%: Url.Content(~/Content/Images/ss.gif) %>" width="11" height="11" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have no idea where the invalid '/' would be in the page, and the expect ';' is already in the other page, please help.  I feel like this should be a quick fix, but I have yet to see where my syntax error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Url.Content(...)` are not wrapped in quotes. E.G.

```
Url.Content(~/Content/Images/banner_left.gif)
```

should be

```
Url.Content("~/Content/Images/banner_left.gif")
```

Comment: Good sir, I am blind!  Thank you very much, I apologize for my stupidity!